# AWS Cloudformation Fn::If wrong validation error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I've got a problem with AWS Cloudformation.
Here is part of the my template

```
       "CreationPolicy": {
            "ResourceSignal": {
                "Fn::If": [
                    "UseCreationPolicy",
                    {
                        "Count": 1,
                        "Timeout": "PT150M"
                    },
                    {
                        "Ref": "AWS::NoValue"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
```

There is no errors while validating locally with `aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file:////...`

But in Cloudformation I have a Validation Error while creating Stack :
`Template error: Fn::If requires a list argument with three elements`

**Did someone has something like that?**

Regarding that I have found only one question (unanswered) on AWS Forum: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=202297

Comment: Your syntax looks correct. Have you tried specifying Count as a string? e.g. { "Count": "1", "Timeout"....   The Fn::If examples in the docs appear to return strings, even when the attribute is an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I guess is with AWS:NoValue which is returned for ResourceSignal. What I think you should try is returning AWS:NoValue for CreationPolicy instead of ResourceSignal so that when the condition UseCreationPolicy is false then the whole CreationPolicy should be waived off.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently doing the exact same thing as the original poster. ( I know it is old ), but the accepted answer is no longer relevant and I want to clarify this for anyone trying to find the answer (like me). To do this in 2023 you can do like this:

```yaml
      ReservedConcurrentExecutions:
        !If
        - IsProdEnv
        - !Sub '${VeryHighLambdaConcurrency}'
        - !Sub '${HighLambdaConcurrency}'
```